# c# settings file save different types

Tags: c#

I have a form which grabs all of the values from the settings file and displays them so that they can be changed.  Some of these values are string types some int and potentially i might add more as we go.

This works well but when i go to save them I struggle with saving the different types.  At present I have

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var txtb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        if (txtb.Tag != "Name")
        {
            string SaveKeyName = txtb.Tag.ToString();
            Properties.Settings.Default[SaveKeyName] = txtb.Text.ToString();
        }
    }
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    this.Close();
}
```

This code works for all the string values but fails because of the type on int values.

So basically the txtb has been given a name which I put in the tag and then the value is the actual text.  I was debating if I could use the tag to add a type value too but this seemed abit flaky.

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: Try using Convert.ToString(type);

Comment: Hi John the message is

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyWrongTypeException' occurred in System.dll

Matthias yeah I think I need to run a different line of code depending on the type expected within the settings file but this changes as you go through it.  I guess I need to find a way of determining what is going to be expected and then that will select my ToString or to and int or whatever